# Curl of a vector field:

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

So I have a force given by

$$ F = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^n(xi+yj+zk)$$

I was wondering how we handle this for the curl...an explanation of the setup would be excellent.

Comment: Didn’t you just ask about divergence for this same function?Computing the curl isn’t that much different since the key part of the computation for both of them is taking partial derivatives of $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In components, if $F$ is a vector,
$$ (\operatorname{curl} F)_i = \varepsilon_{ijk} \partial_j F_k. $$
Using this, it is easy to show that if $g$ is a scalar-valued function,
$$ (\operatorname{curl} (gF))_i = \varepsilon_{ijk}( \operatorname{grad} g )_j F_k + g \varepsilon_{ijk} \partial_j F_k = ((\operatorname{grad} g) \times F + g \operatorname{curl} F )_i, $$
so you just have to compute this for $g=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^n$, $F = (x,y,z)$. It is easy to see that $\operatorname{curl}F=0$, since each component doesn't depend on the others (do the calculation to see what I mean). And further, I showed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1465754/221811) that $\operatorname{grad} g $ is parallel to $F$, so the cross product term is also zero. Hence the whole lot is zero.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using this reference. It has a nice concise description of how to compute the curl of a v-field.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Curl.html

I specifically recommend equation (5). This matrix allows you to compute curl very easily.